# Trying to embed video-js livestream; site refused to connect

Tags: embed, video.js

I have set up a HLS livestream server on a lightsail server. I am trying to embed the live stream on another website but get a ‘domain.com refused to connect’ message in the iframe box.  I can embed other pages (stats, etc) from my same site using the same code just fine, so it seems to be something specific to the video page. There was an x-frame-options deny line in my sites-available/domain.com file but I have removed it and it hasn’t made a difference.

Page I’m trying to embed is https://bacstream.live/live.html which is a video-js player of the livestream.

Answer (score 1):

Solved - the computer I was using must have had a cached version it was loading from; once I did a hard refresh (ctrl+refresh) it is loading fine.  Lesson learned - always check on more than one machine to see if the error is reproducible.